# Asp.net MVC3 long polling with Session

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, session, long-polling

I try to implement long polling in my MVC3 Application.

Long Polling works fine with following code: I can reload the Page without Problems while the thread sleeps.

```
[AsyncTimeout(30 * 1002)]
public void TestAsync()
{
  AsyncManager.OutstandingOperations.Increment();

  var queued = ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(parm =>
  {
    var wait = new AutoResetEvent(false);
    wait.WaitOne(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));

    AsyncManager.OutstandingOperations.Decrement();
  }));
}
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

public ActionResult TestCompleted()
{
  return Json(null);
}
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

But if i use Sessions in the Application like ..

```
this.Session["XXX"] = "Test";
```

I can't reload the Page while the Thread is running. The Page waits unitl the Thread is ready and then the Page will refresh.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: If you're doing this because you want to learn about long polling.. awesome.. if not.. Use SignalR.. this is an area where there is no need to reinvent the wheel when there is an existing well supported solution out there.  Oh and if you're learning about long polling you should probably spend some time in the SignalR source code.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a solution to your problem but it may help.

In MVC you can't execute multiple requests simultaneously for a single user session. The only way to get true asynchronous requests is make the controller a `SessionLess` controller, but then of course you can't read or write to the session.

I experienced this problem when wanting to do asynchronous AJAX requests. I thought by setting the `SessionStateBehaviour` to `ReadOnly` I could at least get read only access to the session as there would be no concurrency issues, but that didn't work either.

This article has more info http://weblogs.asp.net/imranbaloch/archive/2011/05/10/asynccontroller-v-s-sessionless-controller.aspx